# Python while - for nested loop String search on user input

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I was just wondering if I can make a simple script that searches for different strings on user input. Let's say I want to search first time for word "apple" and the second time "orange" and to display all the lines where apples and oranges exist. I want first to be indipendent from the second search.

```
`string = "start"
 while string != "end":
    string = input('Enter fruit: ')
    print("looking for ",string )
    for line in f:
        if "Started" and string in line:
            print("debug")
            print(line)`
```

What this does is works first time and doesn't the second time. I am prompted after the output to enter another fruit but instead of presenting all the lines where the fruit is found it just prompts with another request to enter a fruit.

Comment: I'm guessing that `f` is a file. If so, you need to `.seek` back to the start of the file on each search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have some line like `f = open('BigTextFileFullOfFruit.txt', 'r')` above the snippet you posted:
You can only iterate once over a file. You have to call `f.seek(0)` to go over it again.

Answer (score 0):

This is because `f` is an iterator and it cannot be consumed more than once. After that it is exhausted and will not yield anymore.
 To go around this, you may `seek` to the beginning to re-iterate or save the contents in a `list` for reuse.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Put this inside your outermost loop
string = raw_input("Enter string: ")
f = fp.readline()
while f:
    if f.find(string) >= 0 and "Started":
        print(f, end=' ')
    f = fp.readline()
```